# Why can't see my Jtable in Frame?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

I have a JFrame with a JTable inside, but when code launch the JFrame it don't show Jtable component, the frame shows empty but the data in the Object "datos" its correct.

This frame is launched before a Login screen.

This is the JFrame code:

```
public class PrincipalWindow {

    private void initialize() {
        Principal principal = new Principal();
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

        JTable table = new JTable(modelo);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        modelo = principal.inicializaModelo();

        f.setBounds(10, 10, 800, 600);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));


        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Principal.java

```
public class Principal {
    List<CatalogoVO> listaCatalogo;


    public List<CatalogoVO> getListaCatalogo() {
        return listaCatalogo;
    }


    public void setListaCatalogo(List<CatalogoVO> listaCatalogo) {
        this.listaCatalogo = listaCatalogo;
    }

    public DefaultTableModel inicializaModelo(){
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        CatalogoDAO catalogoDAO = new CatalogoDAO();

        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_REGISTRO);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_MATERIA);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_TITULO);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_TEXTO);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_FECHA);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_CONVOCATORIA);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_LUGAR);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_IDIOMA);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_DESCRIPCION);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_INGRESO);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_UBICACION);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_SOPORTE);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_DIMENSIONES);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_IMPRESOR);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_DEPOSITO);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_CONSERVACION);
        modelo.addColumn(Constantes.COL_OBSERVACIONES);

        listaCatalogo = catalogoDAO.getListaCompleta();

        Object [] datos; //Crea un vector
        for(int i=0;i<listaCatalogo.size();i++){
            datos = new Object[19];
            datos[0] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getRegistro();
            datos[1] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getMateria();
            datos[2] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getTipoDocumental();
            datos[3] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getTitulo();
            datos[4] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getTexto();
            datos[5] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getFecha();
            datos[6] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getConvocatoria();
            datos[7] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getLugar();
            datos[8] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getIdioma();
            datos[9] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getDescripcion();
            datos[10] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getAutor();
            datos[11] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getFormaIngreso();
            datos[12] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getUbicacion();
            datos[13] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getSoporte();
            datos[14] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getDimensiones();
            datos[15] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getImpresor();
            datos[16] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getDepositoLegal();
            datos[17] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getConservacion();
            datos[18] = listaCatalogo.get(i).getObservaciones();

            modelo.addRow(datos);

        }

        return modelo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze the code, line by line:

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
```

Here you create an empty table model

```
JTable table = new JTable(modelo);
```

Here you create a table using this empty table model

```
modelo = principal.inicializaModelo();
```

And here you reassign the modelo variable with a non-empty table model. The table is still using the empty table model.

What you want is:

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = principal.inicializaModelo();
JTable table = new JTable(modelo);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your JTable still has an empty model. You *first* need to initialize your model and *then* create the JTable (or set the model afterwards with `table.setModel(model)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

to this line

```
f.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(table));
```